# How do I create an indicator that overlay Horizontal line that auto-adjust to daily last close?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create an indicator that draws a horizontal line showing the daily last closing price and the line auto adjusts daily.

I'm expecting something like these:

Daily Last Close Line:

[image: Daily Last Close Line]

Daily Last Close visible on lower timeframe:

[image: Daily Last Close visible on lower timeframe]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Yesterday Close", overlay=true)

indexHighTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
indexCurrTF = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
yesterday_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", 
close[indexHighTF])[indexCurrTF]
daily_line = line.new(bar_index, yesterday_close , bar_index-1, yesterday_close, extend= extend.both, color=color.yellow)
line.delete(daily_line[1])
```

It is based on the pinescript manual , see here : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)